# SQL Loader Installation process

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

Any prerequisites for installing SQL Loader (SQLLDR)?

I just have the SQL developer installed and tried going through some topics around it but nothing concrete.

Which Client version should be i installing?

Installed some instant client versions but unsuccessful.

Please assist.

Comment: You'd likely need the full client.  SQL Developer, though, does have the ability to load data from flat files which is likely much more efficient for ad hoc data loads.  If the file can be place on the database server, an external table (which has similar syntax to a `SQL*Loader` control file) is probably more flexible and doesn't require any sort of client install.

Comment: Thanks Justin.. agree to all points and am aware of them as well. It’s just that we are working on some automation and I would need sqlldr for that. Do u have any detailed installation steps?

Comment: Download the full Oracle database (or the 21c client if you happen to be on linux) from OTN.  When you go through the installation process, there is an option to do a client-only install.  If you want to minimize what gets installed, you can do a custom install and pick the particular items that you want (i.e. `SQL*Loader` and little else).